# Angular ng-click does not work- background issue

Tags: php, angularjs

When I click submit on my form, nothing happens and there are no errors. My database connection is fine so I know something is wrong with my angular code or my php file is not being called.

```
<input type="button" value="submit" ng-click="insertdata()">
```

I check my database after clicking submit and nothing is posted.

Here is the script:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.controller('cntrl', function($scope, $http){
      $scope.insertdata=function(){
          $http.post("insert.php", {'id':$scope.id, 'name':$scope.name})
            .success(function() {
              $scope.msg = "Data Inserted";
          })
        }
  });
```

I am going to include the php file in case there is something wrong with that.

My '$http.post' uses this script:

```
<?php
   include "connectdb.php";
   $data = json.decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
   $id=$dbhandle->real_escape_string($data->id);
   $name=$dbhandle->real_escape_string($data->name);

   $query = "INSERT INTO student VALUES($id, '".$name."')";

   $dbhandle->query($query);
?>
```

Comment: You should consider moving to .then() instead of .success() since it is **deprecated**, and also add a .catch() block for proper error handling. So something like this would be much nicer:
          $http.post("insert.php", {'id':$scope.id, 'name':$scope.name})
          .then(function(response) {
              $scope.msg = "Data Inserted";
          }).catch(function(err){
                console.log("Something went wrong - check the err.")
          });
Also check the following link for more details: [.then vs .success](https://www.concretepage.com/forum/thread?qid=461)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :
 $query = "INSERT INTO student VALUES(".$id.", '".$name."')";

Comment: May I ask for clarification on why that worked? As far as syntax for my parameters, can you direct me where that information is for my personal reference?

Comment: this because the params need to be executed as variables, Hence the quotations with  dots are required to let the compiler read them as variable not strings! if that worked don't forget to mark it as a correct answer :)

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow so people with less than 15 reputation can vote, and it is recorded, but does not show up publicly:( Apologize, but have to start somewhere. Was much appreciated though, Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the .then() method in the following way:

```
.then(function(result) {
     // if the request is successful, result contain the answer
     // do your stuff
}, function(error) {
     // if the request is not successful, error contains the error message
})
```